# Aspect for method annotated with annotation which are annotated with another annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop

Is it possible to make pointcut using Spring AOP for methods and type having annotation which was annotated with some annotation.
Here's my custom annotation:

```
@AccessRestriction
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface HasPermission {
}
```

It annotated with this annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AccessRestriction {
}
```

So is it possible to create point cut which will handle all methods which are annotated with any annotation annotated with AccessRestriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.

I made such pointcut:

```
 within(@(@test.security.access.AccessRestriction *) *) ||
 execution(@(@test.security.access.AccessRestriction *) * *(..))
```

Comment: You saved me 8 years later, thanks!