# Spring AOP - Pointcut a annotated annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

Please, someone help me. I want create a pointcut with spring AOP that intercept all method annotated with annotation was inheritance by another.

In my example, I want c

TaskControl.class

```
@Documented
@Target({METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited 
public @interface TaskControl {

    /**
     * taskSelectorAnnotation
     * @return
     */
    Class<? extends Annotation>[] value() default {}; 
}
```

TypeTaskCriteria.class

```
@Documented
@Target({METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@TaskSelectorStrategy(value = TypeTaskSelector.class)
@TaskControl
public @interface TypeTaskCriteria {

    Class<?> genericType() default void.class;

    boolean defaultPreTask() default true;

    Class<? extends Task>[] pre() default {};

    boolean defaultPostTask() default true;

    Class<? extends Task>[] post() default {};

}
```

ExampleTest.class has one method like the follow:

```
    @TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreRetrieveTask.class, post = PostRetrieveTask.class)
    public Page<T> retrieve(Integer pageNumber,
        Integer pageSize,
        String filterExpression,
        String sortExpression,
        String expandExpression,
        Map<String, String> parameters) throws InvalidParameterException, UnexpectedException {
```

And my pointcut is:

```
    @Around("@annotation(br.org.ccee.fusion.core.api.task.TaskControl)")
    public Object executeChains(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
```

(if I change to the TypeTaskCriteria, the pointcut works fine)

Someone has a anwser ????

Thanks !!!!

Valdir Scarin

Comment: The solution was post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806731/aspect-for-method-annotated-with-annotation-which-are-annotated-with-another-ann. That's works !!!!

Comment: In your question you are talking about inheritance, but actually inheritance is completely irrelevant here, nothing extends anything else. Maybe you want to rephrase your question a bit.